# Screenshot всего экрана

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать screenshot всего экрана и записать все это в файл .png or .jpg? Собственно запись я и сам выполню на нажатие кнопки, а вот как сделать screenshot? Может кто подскажет? Нажатие кнопки Print Screen сразу отпадает. И чтобы скрин появился в PictureBox1. Спасибо всем за помощь.

Comment: тривиальная задача, очень легко гуглится

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно так:

```
Graphics graph = null;

var bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);

bmp.Save("filename");
```

Как в пикчуре бокс положить битмап догадаетесь?

Comment: ОО Спасибо!!!

Comment: Что-то ничего не происходит. Вот также должно быть?


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ... Код из ответа
    }

Comment: если так то должен появиться файл filename cо скриншотом в папке программы

Comment: а понятно,а можно сделать сохранение через  SaveFileDialog?

Comment: Конечно :-)

Comment: Вот так же?
bmp.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);

Comment: @RconPro, не легче попробовать?